# Combining this with other classes selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just a quick one. I have following function:

```
$('.menu').on('change', function() {
  $('.menu, .rows').toggle();
});
```

and I want to replace the second `.menu` with `this`. How can I combine it like:

```
$(this, '.rows').toggle();
```

does not work.

Thanks

Comment: $('.rows').add(this).toggle();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, try with:

```
$('.rows', this).toggle();
```

Comment: `$(selector, context)` is probably going to be deprecated soon; it just turns around and calls `$(context).find(...)` nowadays.

Comment: I know how works internally, but where can I read information about it *is probably going to be deprecated soon*?

Comment: It was a comment from Dave Methvin somewhere in a comment stream on a pull request, I don't have the link. It relates to the ridiculous number of signatures the `jQuery` function has. I suppose you don't really have to worry about it until/unless a deprecation notice shows up (I don't see one yet). "Soon" was probably overstating it. :-)

Comment: Oh, I see, I was googling but couldn't find anything about it. It's true what you say about the number of signatures. Anyway, to me, this way is faster (thinking in *write less, do more*) than the others. Thank you for the explanation 

Answer (score 4):

You can set [context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) for selector, like so,

```
$('.rows', this).toggle();
```

or you can use [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), like this

```
 $(this).find('.rows').toggle();
```

Comment: As note, the use of `.find()` is what you get using `$('a', this)`.

Comment: @talemyn: `$(selector, context)` just does a couple of up-front checks and turns around to do `$(context).find(selector)`. Hard to imagine many scenarios where the microseconds those checks took actually matter. :-) (I just use `find`, myself, but...)

Comment: I didn't say it was **noticeably** faster . . . just faster.   :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to combine/select multiple elements, use the [`.add()` method](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$('.menu').on('change', function() {
  $('.rows').add(this).toggle();
});
```

or:

```
$('.menu').on('change', function() {
  $(this).add('.rows').toggle();
});
```

You were using the [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1), `$(this, '.rows')`, which is equivalent to:

```
$('.menu').on('change', function() {
  $('.rows').find('.menu').toggle();
});
```